# Working with bi-dirctional JACKSON

Tags: java, json, jackson, gson, bidirectional

first, sorry about my bad english;

Second, I have the following Code:

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")    

public class UserAccount implements Serializable  {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private List<Venda> vendas;

    }
```

And the following:

```
public class Venda implements Serializable  {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private UserAccount cliente;

    }
```

> So, everything is okay and get the json from serialize on this way (when I ask for an UserAccount):

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,    
    "vendas": [
      {
        "id": 1,        
        "cliente": 1,        
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

> And when I ask for a Venda:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,    
    "cliente": {
      "id": 1,      
      "vendas": [
        {
          "id": 1,        
          "cliente": 1         
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

The problem is, I don't need the "cliente" information on "vendas"  in the first case, but in the second one I need the "cliente" information, However I don't want his "vendas", cause I already got it before;

I already trid @JsonIgnore and didn't work for me, what should I do?

PS: I'm working with GSON to get the .Class from JSON, and I get a terrible Exception because sometimes cliente is an Object and sometimes is Integer, so if you guys have another solution that makes cliente and vendas don't change their type, i would to know too. :(

Comment: Either use Gson or Jackson. Not both

Comment: @cricket_007 i gonna make new tests using only Jackson and, after, i will come back and show the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this using Jackson's [Mix-in feature](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonMixInAnnotations).  The Mixin feature is a class were you can specify json annotations (on the class, fields and getters/setters) and they apply to the bean/pojo you serialize. Basically, a mixin allows adding annotations at run time and without chaning the bean/pojo source file. You use Jackson's [module feature](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFeatureModules) to apply a Mixin at run time.

So I created one mixin that dynamically adds `@JsonIgnore` annotation to vendas getter method of `UserAccount` class, and another mixin that adds `@JsonIgnore` annotation to cliente getter method of `Venda` class.

Here is the modified `UserAccount` class:

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")
public class UserAccount implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private List<Venda> vendas = new ArrayList<>();

    public Long getId() { return id; }
    public void setId(Long id) { this.id = id; }
    public List<Venda> getVendas() { return vendas; }
    public void        setVendas(List<Venda> vendas) { this.vendas = vendas; }
    public void        addVenda(Venda v) { 
        this.vendas.add(v);
        v.setCliente(this);
    }

    /**
     * a Jackson module that is also a Jackson mixin 
     * it adds @JsonIgnore annotation to getVendas() method of UserAccount class
     */
    public static class FilterVendas extends SimpleModule {
        @Override
        public void setupModule(SetupContext context) {
            context.setMixInAnnotations(UserAccount.class, FilterVendas.class);
        }
        // implementation of method is irrelevant. 
        // all we want is the annotation and method's signature 
        @JsonIgnore
        public List<Venda> getVendas() { return null; }  
    }
```

Here is the modified `Venda` class:

```
public class Venda implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private UserAccount cliente;

    public Long getId() { return id; }
    public void setId(Long id) { this.id = id; }
    public UserAccount getCliente() { return cliente; }
    public void        setCliente(UserAccount cliente) { this.cliente = cliente; }

    /**
     * a Jackson module that is also a Jackson mixin 
     * it adds @JsonIgnore annotation to getCliente() method of Venda class
     */
    public static class FilterCliente extends SimpleModule {
        @Override
        public void setupModule(SetupContext context) {
            context.setMixInAnnotations(Venda.class, FilterCliente.class);
        }
        // implementation of method is irrelevant. 
        // all we want is the annotation and method's signature 
        @JsonIgnore
        public UserAccount getCliente() { return null; }
    }
}
```

and the test method with run time object mapper configuration:

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    Venda v = new Venda();
    UserAccount ua = new UserAccount();
    v.setId(1L);
    ua.setId(1L);
    ua.addVenda(v);
    try {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        System.out.println("UserAccount: (unfiltered)");
        System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(ua));

        mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        // register module at run time to apply filter
        mapper.registerModule(new Venda.FilterCliente());
        System.out.println("UserAccount: (filtered)");
        System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(ua));

        mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        System.out.println("Venda: (unfiltered)");
        System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(v));

        mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        // register module at run time to apply filter
        mapper.registerModule(new UserAccount.FilterVendas());
        System.out.println("Venda: (filtered)");
        System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(ua));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

output:

```
UserAccount: (unfiltered)
{"id":1,"vendas":[{"id":1,"cliente":1}]}
UserAccount: (filtered)
{"id":1,"vendas":[{"id":1}]}
Venda: (unfiltered)
{"id":1,"cliente":{"id":1,"vendas":[{"id":1,"cliente":1}]}}
Venda: (filtered)
{"id":1}
```

Comment: First at all, thanks for help, but what I would like is  something like: 
     Venda: (filtered)
    {"id":1,"cliente":{"id":1}}

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, I got the solution by this way:

```
public class CustomClienteSerializer extends JsonSerializer<UserAccount> {

@Override
public void serialize(UserAccount cliente, JsonGenerator generator, SerializerProvider provider)
        throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

    cliente.setVendas(null);
    generator.writeObject(cliente);

}
```

}

and adding this on my venda class:

```
@JsonSerialize(using = CustomClienteSerializer.class)   
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private UserAccount cliente;
```

So... I got the json as I wanted!